# Getting the last updated name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having a table having records like this:

```
+------+------+
| ID   | name |
+------+------+
|    1 | A    |
|    2 | B    |
|    3 | C    |
|    4 | A    |
|    5 | B    |
|    6 | A    |
|    7 | A    |
|    8 | A    |
+------+------+
```

I need to get value of A after it was last updated from a different value, for example here it would be the row at ID 6.

Comment: What have you tried? What problems did you encounter?

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Using sql server tried with ranks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [Lag function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)...

```
SELECT Max([ID]) 
FROM   (SELECT [name], [ID], 
               Lag([name]) OVER (ORDER BY [ID]) AS PrvVal 
        FROM   tablename) tbl 
WHERE  [name] = 'A' 
       AND prvval <> 'A'
```

Online Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a55eb/2/0

If you want to get the whole row, you can do this...

```
SELECT   Top 1 *
FROM     (SELECT [name], [ID], 
               Lag([name]) OVER (ORDER BY [ID]) AS PrvVal 
          FROM   tablename) tbl 
WHERE    [name] = 'A' AND prvval <> 'A'   
ORDER BY [ID] DESC
```

Online Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a55eb/22/0

Answer (score 3):

Try this query (MySQL syntax):

```
select min(ID) 
from records 
where name = 'A' 
and ID >= 
(
  select max(ID) 
  from records 
  where name <> 'A'
);
```

Illustration:

```
select * from records;
+------+------+
| ID   | name |
+------+------+
|    1 | A    |
|    2 | B    |
|    3 | C    |
|    4 | A    |
|    5 | B    |
|    6 | A    |
|    7 | A    |
|    8 | A    |
+------+------+
```

-- run query:

```
+---------+
| min(ID) |
+---------+
|       6 |
+---------+
```

Comment: This really is a good approach and helped me in getting desired results thaks mate

Answer (score 1):

The ANSI SQL below uses a self-join on the previous id.

And the where-clause gets those with a name that's different from the previous.

```sql
select max(t1.ID) as ID
from YourTable as t1
left join YourTable as t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID+1
where (t1.name <> t2.name or t2.name is null)
  and t1.name = 'A';
```

It should work on most RDBMS, including MS Sql Server.

*Note that with the `ID+1` that there's an assumption that are no gaps between the ID's.*